# MS-DOS how to get output of command as variable

Tags: dos

I've written a program that returns keycodes as integers for DOS
but i don't know how to get it's output as a variable.

Note: I'm using MS-DOS 7 / Windows 98, so i can't use `FOR /F` or `SET /P`

Does anyone know how i could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few solutions are described by Eric Pement [here](http://www.pement.org/sed/bat_env.htm). However, for older versions of `cmd` the author was forced to use external tools.

For example, program tools like `STRINGS` by Douglas Boling, allows for following code:

`echo Greetings! | STRINGS hi=ASK # puts "Greetings!" into %hi%`

Same goes for `ASET` by Richard Breuer:

`echo Greetings! | ASET hi=line       # puts "Greetings!" into %hi%`

One of alternative pure DOS solutions needs the program output to be redirected to the file (named `ANSWER.DAT` in example below) and then uses a specially prepared batch file. To cite the aforementioned page:

> [I]n the batch file we need to be able to issue the command
>   `set MYVAR={the contents of ANSWER.DAT go here}`. This is a difficult task, since MS-DOS doesn't offer an easy way to prepend `"set MYVAR="` to a file [...]
>
> Normal DOS text files and batch files end all lines with two consecutive bytes: a carriage return (<kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd>, hex 0D, or ASCII 13) and a linefeed (<kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>, hex 0A or ASCII 10). In the batch file, you must be able to embed a <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd> in the middle of a line.
>
> Many text editors have a way to do this: via a <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd> (DOS EDIT with Win95/98, VDE), via a <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> prefix (Emacs, PFE), via direct entry with <kbd>ALT</kbd> and the numeric keypad (QEdit, Multi-Edit), or via a designated function key (Boxer). Other editors absolutely will not support this (Notepad, Editpad, EDIT from MS-DOS 6.22 or earlier; VIM can insert a linefeed only in binary mode, but not in its normal text mode).
>
> If you can do it, your batch file might look like this:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> :: assume that the datafile exists already in ANSWER.DAT
> echo set myvar=^J | find "set" >PREFIX.DAT
> copy PREFIX.DAT+ANSWER.DAT  VARIAB.BAT
> call VARIAB.BAT
> echo Success! The value of myvar is: [%myvar%].
> :: erase temp files ...
> for %%f in (PREFIX.DAT ANSWER.DAT VARIAB.BAT) do del %%f >NUL
> ```
>
> Where you see the ^J on line 3 above, the linefeed should be embedded at that point. Your editor may display it as a square box with an embedded circle.